# Python - Unable to connect to 2 different databases like hive and iris in same python program

Tags: python, hive, jaydebeapi, intersystems-iris, multi-database-connections

I am trying to connect to hive database and IRIS Intersystems Databases using jaydebeapi in python.
I am able to connect to one database at a time. While trying to connect to other database, I am getting the below error

**"Class org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver is not found"** or
**"Class com.intersystems.jdbc.IRISDriver is not found"**

lin1 - hive_con = jd.connect(java_driver_class, jdbc_conn_url, [hive_user, hive_pass],jarfile)

lin2 - iris_con = jd.connect(iris_driver_class, iris_conn_url, [iris_user, iris_pass],jarfile)

If I try to execute the above code, only the first lin1 executes and the other one gives out exception.

If I comment out the first line, then second line lin2 works fine.
I tried to close one connection before opening the other, still the issue is same.
I want the the both connections to work in same program.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass in both jar files like this:
jar_files = [jar1, jar2]
lin1 - hive_con = jd.connect(java_driver_class, jdbc_conn_url, [hive_user, hive_pass],jar_files)

lin2 - iris_con = jd.connect(iris_driver_class, iris_conn_url, [iris_user, iris_pass],jar_files)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).